# Memory Allocation algorithm in c

Tags: c, memory-management

Is the memory allocation system of C completely random or does it use pseudo random generator ?
What is the actual algorithm for memory allocation that happens at the back ?

Comment: Are you talking about dynamic allocation? If so, you can provide even your own implementation..

Comment: `Is the memory allocation system of C completely random or does it use pseudo random generator?` What makes you think it's random at all? `What is the actual algorithm for memory allocation that happens at the back?` This is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Right now I am looking at FreeRTOS source code and seeing... 4 different implementations for `malloc`. With a comment inviting me to write the fifth one.

Comment: I meant the dynamic memory allocation. The addresses that the computer provides for instance when we need the nodes of a linked list are pretty random but still sometimes we can figure out a pattern when we declare two ints consecutively.So I wanted to know the exact algorithm followed to allocate dynamically ?

Comment: Also @EugeneSh. What do you mean by we can provide our own implementation.. ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Write your own `malloc`, `free` and friends. These are not built-ins, but library functions.

Comment: It would be great if you can please tell me how to write an implementation and how different ones are written..Also I did not understand what the @Jashaszun meant by implementation dependent

Comment: Here's the recent glibc version of `malloc()` https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.21/malloc_8c_source.html read, be busy and understand ... ;-)

Comment: There is a memory region allocated for "heap" for every program. `malloc` and `free` are managing a data structure tracking the usage of that region. That's all. `malloc` will return a pointer to unused space, updating the database. `free` will mark this region as unused updating the database as well.  The data structure and algorithms are a implementation specific.

Comment: @alk You have chosen the hardest way :) Better go [here](http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html)

Comment: I did it, and gained a lot from digging my way through it. Why shouldn't others do it, as well? ;->> @EugeneSh.

Comment: You got evil @alk :P :P Did you actually implement the malloc after that ? The link you provided seemed alot to read. :v

Comment: It's nicely crosslinked, so what? If you want it harder, pull the sources and use vi as a reader and grep for searching (and hopefully finding, I did btw, had to)... ;) @karankapoor And no, I was debugging some mystery ... :-S

Comment: And no, the memory allocation system of glibc is not (completely) random, as can be proven by reading (at least the comments in) the source(s) I linked in one of my previous comments.

Comment: Why would it be random?  It doesn't need to be random. It would take a lot of extra effort to make it random, for next-to-no gain. There are more important attributes than radomness, (eg. performance).  Nobody wants a random malloc.  A random malloc is not easily possible because of alignment and the metadata.  No, no random.

Comment: @MartinJames Well, there *is* address randomization techniques, recently being employed in modern OSs for security purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't do memory allocation. *You*, the programmer, have to do it yourself based on the simple primitives `malloc()` and `free()`, which do nothing but ask the OS for free chunks of memory to give you.